# ?attr/colorPrimary in drawable results in no color lollipop

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-theme, android-attributes

I have a drawable like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I have two different themes which uses different colors for colorPrimary.

when I use this drawable, it results in no color

color codes for both the themes are as follows

```
darkTheme: #50c5ff
lightTheme: #90a1fc
```

how could I solve this issue?

**Update:**

when I use

```
<solid android:color="?android:colorPrimary" />
```

it results in black background color

I am running my code on android 7.1.1

Comment: what's keeking you from trying "@color/colorPrimary" ?

Comment: this is a theme attribute, I don't have any color value named colorPrimary

Answer (score 0):

```
<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

instead of

```
<solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to give color code instead of giving a color reference.
for ex.

```
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
```